# How to loaded odbc with the build-in apache and php5.5 on MacOsX (el Capitan)

Tags: php, macos, odbc, osx-elcapitan, iodbc

I'm currently trying to run (i)odbc through the php extension. I have searched during these three last days and I have no clue how to config the build-in php5.5 of MacOsx to load the odbc extension. I got no problem to connect to odbc but just to load the extension.

Have you an idea?

Comment: In /private/etc/php.ini the line `extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll` is uncomment. But the odbc extension is not loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The build-in Apache-PhP5 in Capitan is not installed with the extension ODBC. Prefer to install a new config with brew and the extension odbc.